# Android. How to improve recycler view performance?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-relativelayout, android-constraintlayout

I have a list of items and I'm using RecyclerView to showing it.
This is an example of my list:
[image]

I need to understand what is better to use for item layout: RelativeLayout or ConstraintLayout in my case.

On the one hand, the RelativeLayout is considered as deprecated and recommended to use ConstraintLayout. But at the same time, it is better to use the ConstraintLayout when there are many child views, and then we will get a performance improvement. But I only have two child views and I have a feeling that the ConstraintLayout  can only hurt.

Please tell me which view group is better to choose in my case?

Comment: [This should help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59628341/constraintlayout-vs-relativelayout-performance-2020)

Answer (score 1):

Choosing Layout to build UI is specifically Developer choice, and is based on how your layout is complex, if you have a layout with many child views, it is better to use combination of Layout like parent Layout is Relative inside cardview inside constraint layout and you can place textview and images, Choosing Layouts based on Permormance is not ideal choice, if you care most of performance forcus on backend logic

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that use Constraint Layout .ConstraintLayout has a better performance since it's introduced.A performance benchmark of ConstraintLayout vs RelativeLayout is available in this official blog post by Google - ConstraintLayout is ~40% faster.Now a days most of them are using it.And it will fit for all resolution of the screen